# sleep system call in thread

Tags: unix, pthreads, sleep

I am using pthread library for multi-threading. Inside thread function, I use sleep system call. Will this block a single thread or the whole process. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, `sleep` affects only the calling thread.  Real, kernel-managed threads run independently of each other.  In an app that has "green" threads, though (not native to the OS; managed by the app itself), a system call that blocks may block everything.  But that kind of brokenness is rather rare -- software managing green threads tends to provide a whole runtime environment, including ways to `sleep` without resorting to a system call.

The better question is...do you really need to `sleep` at all?  Time-based synchronization tends to lead to race conditions and fragile apps.  There's a way for threads to wait on and trigger each other; that leads to better determinism.

Comment: In my code, there's no synchronization between threads. Each thread is detached. I just use sleep syscall to follow the assignment description which states the thread should sleep for some seconds after doing some jobs